# Login page with Xamarin MvvmCross-Forms - preventing back navigation on Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I am trying to implement a login page for an MvvmCross-Forms application. When the application is launched, the user should be presented a login screen if they are not logged in, or directed to the home page if they are. The user is directed to the home page when they log in, and directed to the login page when they log out from the home page. Pretty standard stuff - what you'd expect from an app with authentication.

I have implemented this using MvvmCross ViewModel navigation, but every navigation allows the user to press the 'Back' button in the title bar on Android, or use the hardware back button. As a user, I'd expect the home page after logging in to be the 'root' page, and to only be able to get back to the login screen by explicitly deciding to log out.

I understand that a typical way of doing this in Xamarin Forms would be to create a custom Page Presenter under the Droid project, which intercepts calls to `Show()` and clears the back stack on navigation to the home page or the login page (eg the top answer for [Xamarin MvvmCross Android Prevent Back Button returning to previous View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004915/xamarin-mvvmcross-android-prevent-back-button-returning-to-previous-view)). However, it seems that MvvmCross-Forms deliberately prevents you from implementing this functionality - the `MvxFormsDroidPagePresenter` class inherits from the cross-platform `MvxFormsPagePresenter` instead of the android-specific `MvxAndroidViewPresenter`.

I can see two options - either try and use a single ViewModel/View for the login, and the home page, or rip out some of the `MvxAndroidViewPresenter` functionality and put it into my own custom Android presenter. How would this behaviour be implemented idiomatically in MvvmCross-Forms?

Comment: You can try using https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/LoginDemo

Answer (score 2):

Approach is wrong. What you want to do is set your home page as root and immediately after that do ModalPush for Login page in case user is not logged in. When the user logs in do ModalPop and you are back to root which is home page.

In case user is logged in than you are right where you're supposed to be - root, which is home page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I been struggling to solve for the question originally posted.  I'm now convinced your approach is the correct one.  You don't want to be messing with the root.