# Open view without navigation in MvvmCross Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I am trying to create a simple login view in an MvvmCross (using the Xamarin.Forms option) which switches to another view after the login button is pressed, however when I do something like `this.ShowViewModel<MainViewModel>();` or `navigationService.Navigate<MainViewModel>();`

it leaves a navigate back button which switches back the view to the login view.

How do I show a different view but prevent it from adding a back button?

Below is my LoginViewModel.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using MvvmCross.Core.Navigation;
using MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels;

namespace MvvmForms.MySampleApp.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class LoginViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        readonly IMvxNavigationService navigationService;

        public LoginViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
        {
            this.navigationService = navigationService;
        }

        ...

        public ICommand ShowMainPageCommand => new MvxCommand(ShowInfoPage);

        private void ShowMainPage()
        {
            navigationService.Navigate<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my LoginPage.xaml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mvx:MvxContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:forms="using:Xamarin.Forms"
    xmlns:mvx="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Core;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
    x:Class="MvvmForms.MySampleApp.Core.Pages.LoginPage" 
    Title="Login Page"
>
<mvx:MvxContentPage.Padding Thickness="5, 0, 5, 95">
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
        <On Platform="Android" Value="5, 0, 5, 0" />
        <On Platform="iOS" Value="5, 20, 5, 0" />
    </OnPlatform>
</mvx:MvxContentPage.Padding>
<StackLayout Spacing="10" Orientation="Vertical">
    <Label FontSize="24" Text="Enter your nickname in the box below" />
    <Entry Placeholder="Who are you?" TextColor="Red" Text="{Binding YourNickname}" />
    <Label FontSize="24" Text="{Binding Hello}" />
    <Button x:Name="LoginButton" Text="Login" Command="{Binding ShowMainPageCommand}" />
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove login page from navigation stack after you went to another page

Push you page

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
```

Now if you have the reference to Login page you can do

```
Navigation.RemovePage(loginPage);
```

Otherwise find your page on stack and remove it

```
 var pages = Navigation.NavigationStack.ToList();
  foreach (var page in pages)
     {
         if (page.GetType() == typeof(LoginPage))
              Navigation.RemovePage(page);
     }
```

Comment: Thanks, but how & where do I do that? Can you please provide some code?

Comment: Thanks, I finally managed to get it working by adding your for loop in the `OnAppearing` method of my MainPage.xaml.cs file & changing `page.GetType() != typeof(LoginPage)` to `page.GetType() == typeof(LoginPage)`. One minor thing though, the back button disappears after the view has appeared. Is it possible to remove the page before the view appears?

Comment: I fixed !=, this part was done to remove everything but certain page. Now, answering your question: if you do that in MainPage then button will appear. You should do it right after you call Navigate to main page.

Comment: I tried that using the LoginPage.xaml.cs (as I don't have access to the Navigation object in the LoginViewModel & the navigationService doesn't  seem to have any stack features), but that breaks the next set of navigation in the Main Page as well as all the MvvmCross bindings.

Comment: If you are doing navigation from the model then you need to pass Navigation object to it somehow (directly or via page which has Navigation object). if you provide sample project I might help you more. I don't have exact details what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry, I kind of missed the beginning that you are using MvvmCross. Then it is question for them, I was talking about pure Xamarin navigation. I know that access to navigation stack for Prism is requested feature and currently in development but not sure about MvvmCross

Comment: doesn't matter, at least your answer helped to some extent. For now I removed it as an accepted answer and gave a vote up instead.

Comment: take a look on this. would it help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45084823/xamarin-forms-with-prism-remove-a-page-from-the-stack

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look. By the way, I am not sure as I didn't test it yet, but it seems that what I am trying to do with MvvmCross already exists in [Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/).

Comment: Just did a test. Xamarin already has support mvvm, so I don't need to use a different framework for that & since this answer helped solve the problem for the most part I just accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This methodology may work for you.

_navigation is of type NaviagtionPage

page is the Page you'd like to be the new root.

```
var root  = _navigation.Navigation.NavigationStack.First();
_navigation.Navigation.InsertPageBefore(page);
_navigation.PopToRootAsync();
```

This will insert your page as a root page and eliminate the login page

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with _navigation being a NavigationPage. Is that an MvvmCross component?

Comment: I have tried the method you provided by just using the Navigation from MainPage as well as the LoginPage (both MvxContentPage instances), but either the MainPage isn't in the stack or its too late (which causes the back button to be visible).

Comment: Do you make your LoginPage as NavigationPage?

Comment: Another simpler methodology could be to initialize the app as if the user has logged in, then push the login page as a modal page. Modal pages will not contain the back button

Comment: The LoginPage is not a `NavigationPage`, but an instance of `MvvmCross.Forms.Core.MvxContentPage`. I added the code for the LoginPage as well. How do I use modal pages in MvvmCross while still using Xamarin.Forms rather than rebuilding the screens in iOS as well as Android? I can't find anything about Xamarin.Forms modals in MvvmCross.

Comment: Sorry, i am not too familiar with MvvmCross and it seems one've their approaches includes avoiding modal pages. Here is a link to someone with the same issue, however it does involve a little bit of work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004915/xamarin-mvvmcross-android-prevent-back-button-returning-to-previous-view

Comment: Depending on how similar MvvmCross is to normal Xamarin.Forms, you may be able to change App.Current.MainPage. In my solution I am not using MvvmCross, but I am using a Mvvm approach with a custom NavigationService to handle Navigation. If you can modify the NavigationService, there are likely several methodologies allowing a 'SetRoot' like method. My original post was how I implemented that method.