# Xamarin Forms with Prism: Remove a page from the stack

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

When I navigate from page A to page B, I need to remove page A.

How can I do this with Prism's navigation service in Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be to have your page implement `INavigationAware` and in the `OnNavigatedFrom`, call `Navigatin.RemovePage(this)`.

Comment: I didn't find the Navigation.RemovePage(). I'm using Prism 6.3.0. In which version the RemovePage() exists?

Comment: I am with this approach, but with a tabbed page... I need to remove some tabs, when some business rules happens... but I cant do that... this interface do not works !!!

Answer (score 4):

There are a few scenarios that people run into on this one.

As a common example say you have a LoginPage, and once the user successfully logs in you want to Navigate to the MainPage. Your code might look something like the following:

```
public class App : PrismApplication
{
    protected override async void OnInitialized()
    {
        await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("LoginPage");
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes()
    {
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<LoginPage>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainPage>();
    }
}

public class LoginPageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public DelegateCommand LoginCommand { get; }

    private async void OnLoginCommandExecuted()
    {
        // Do some validation

        // Notice the Absolute URI which will reset the navigation stack
        // to start with MainPage
        await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("/MainPage");
    }
}
```

Now if what you're looking for is some flow where your navigation stack looks like `MainPage/ViewA` and what you want is `MainPage/ViewB` and you don't want to reinitialize MainPage, then this is something that we are currently evaluating and wanting to improve this so you could do something like `_navigationService.NavigateAsync("../ViewB")`. In the mean time what I might suggest is something like this:

```
public class ViewAViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public DelegateCommand ViewBCommand { get; }

    private async void OnViewBCommandExecuted()
    {
        var parameters = new NavigationParameters
        {
            { "navigateTo", "ViewB" }
        };

        await _navigationService.GoBackAsync(parameters);
    }
}

public class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase, INavigatedAware
{
    public async void OnNavigatingTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        if(parameters. GetNavigationMode() == NavigationMode.Back && 
           parameters.TryGetValue("navigateTo", out string navigateTo))
        {
            await _navigationService.NavigateAsync(navigateTo);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do have a flow like how you explained in the 2nd example I want to go from `MainPage\PageA` to `MainPage\PageB` but without reinitializing `MainPage`, so basically I just want to remove `PageA` when going to `PageB`. I am trying to figure out your solution, but for now I can't really understand it. Why on `OnViewBCommandExecuted` you go back?

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your example, or I just can't figure it out yet.

Comment: can you describe the idea, maybe I can figure it out that way?

Comment: Since I'm on `PageA` I GoBack to `MainPage` passing it a parameter to let the MainPage know that I want to navigate to `PageB`. This allows me to properly navigate. If I wanted to pass additional NavigationParameters from PageA to PageB, when I do the Navigation from the `MainPage` I would simply pass in the parameters there.

Comment: Aha! thanks! Is there a way to tell Prism that if I navigate by Uri to for example `/MainPage/PageA` if that already Uri already "exists", meaning the navigation stack looks exactly like that, then do not instantiate them? Because from what I tried (and I think you already said it in your first example) it resets and recreates `MainPage` and `PageA`.

Comment: It would be great if `Prism` supported that. Something like `navigationService.NavigateAsync(new Uri('MainePage\PageA', ...., createOnlyNewPages: true)`

Comment: I am not sure if it makes sense what I am asking

Comment: that would really somewhat difficult since you're navigating ultimately be a string key and that has to resolve back to a type to even try to compare to. You're welcome of course to open an issue and make your case. I don't think it's something that we would do though to be honest

Comment: I wonder, could it be another solution to call `Navigation.RemovePage(pageA)` after I know `PageB` was navigated to?

Comment: I need to do that from a Page obviously

Comment: If you had something like `MainPage/PageA/PageB` and wanted to remove `PageA` you might use `IEventAggregator` to publish an event with the key of the page you want to remove and listen for it from the code behind on `Page` and then simply have it remove itself

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the latest xamarin its like it doesn't change the page any idea why ?

Answer (score 4):

> Given: "NavigationPage/ViewA/ViewB/ViewC/ViewD"
>
> Navigate from ViewD with:
>   NavigationService.NavigateAsync("../../../ViewE");
>
> Results in: "NavigationPage/ViewA/ViewE"

Referred from [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/112839/navigating-to-previous-page-in-stack-using-prism-navigation)

Need Prism >= 7.0

Answer (score 2):

I do it that way, it's simpler.

navigationService.NavigateAsync("../PageB");

I am using Prims 7.0.0.396.